# How to input and output an Seq of an object to a function in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sequence

I want to parse a column to get split values using Seq of an object

```
case class RawData(rawId: String, rawData: String)

case class SplitData(
                        rawId: String,
                        rawData: String,
                        split1: Option[Int],
                        split2: Option[String],
                        split3: Option[String],
                        split4: Option[String]
                      )

def rawDataParser(unparsedRawData: Seq[RawData]): Seq[RawData] = {       
  unparsedrawData.map(rawData => {
    val split = rawData.address.split(", ")

    rawData.copy(
      split1 = Some(split(0).toInt),
      split2 = Some(split(1)),
      split3 = Some(split(2)),
      split4 = Some(split(3))
    )
  })
}

val rawDataDF= Seq[(String, String)](
  ("001", "Split1, Split2, Split3, Split4"),
  ("002", "Split1, Split2, Split3, Split4")
).toDF("rawDataID", "rawData")

val rawDataDS: Dataset[RawData] = rawDataDF.as[RawData]
```

I need to use rawDataParser function to parse my rawData. However, the parameter to the function is of type Seq. I am not sure how should I convert rawDataDS as an input to function to parse the raw data. some form of guidance to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: `def addressParser(unparsedAddress: Seq[AddressData])` If you have a `Seq` of `AddressData` what do you need to parse? Should that be `Seq[AddressRawData]`??

Answer (score 2):

Each `DataSet` is further divided into `partitions`. You can use `mapPartitions` with a mapping `Iterator[T] => Iterator[U]` to convert a `DataSet[T]` into a `DataSet[U]`.

So, you can just use your `addressParser` as the argument for `mapPartition`.

```scala
val rawAddressDataDS =
  spark.read
    .option("header", "true")
    .csv(csvFilePath)
    .as[AddressRawData]

val addressDataDS =
  rawAddressDataDS
    .map { rad =>
      AddressData(
        addressId = rad.addressId,
        address = rad.address,
        number = None,
        road = None,
        city = None,
        country = None
      )
    }
    .mapPartitions { unparsedAddresses =>
      addressParser(unparsedAddresses.toSeq).toIterator
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by " return it as addressId, address, Seq[AddressData]" ? What is "it" ? And what do you want to do with "it" ?